# Change swipe gesture functionality

Tags: react-native, swipe, navigator

I'm working on a book and I want to change the swipe-back and swipe-forward functionality. I want to keep the swiping animation but on swipe-back for instance I want to change the chapter of the book, so I need do go to a custom ref, not to the previous route. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I don't understand a word of your question. Maybe you can start by telling what environment/language you are using?

Answer (score -1):

Check out these navigator methods:

```
getCurrentRoutes() - returns the current list of routes

jumpBack() - Jump backward without unmounting the current scene

jumpForward() - Jump forward to the next scene in the route stack

jumpTo(route) - Transition to an existing scene without unmounting

push(route) - Navigate forward to a new scene, squashing any scenes that you could jumpForward to

pop() - Transition back and unmount the current scene

replace(route) - Replace the current scene with a new route

replaceAtIndex(route, index) - Replace a scene as specified by an index

replacePrevious(route) - Replace the previous scene

immediatelyResetRouteStack(routeStack) - Reset every scene with an array of routes

popToRoute(route) - Pop to a particular scene, as specified by its route. All scenes after it will be unmounted

popToTop() - Pop to the first scene in the stack, unmounting every other scene
```

You could do something like this:

```
this.refs.navigator.jumpTo(route)
```

All of the methods are documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html).

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html